# Xamarin.Forms.Switch sends Toggled event when value is updated

Tags: c#, events, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm still debuting with `Xamarin.Forms`. So far so good, if I put aside a few pesky bugs I encountered. Here's the new guy. Maybe one of you could tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Basically, I have a `Xamarin.Forms.Switch` on my interface, and I'm listening for changes in its state with the `Toggled` event. The doc says about this event: "Event that is raised when this Switch is toggled **by the user**."

Unfortunately, when I update the value of the switch programmatically, the event fires.

```
var mySwitch = new Switch ();
mySwitch.Toggled += (object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("Switch.Toggled event sent");
};
mySwitch.IsToggled = true;
```

Any way to prevent the event from firing / to know that it's not the user who triggered it?

Comment: It should read like the SwitchCell Event, "Triggered when the switch has changed value". You can either hack it via a dirty flag set & check when programmatically updating your model or create an inherited class from it and create your own EventHandle Delegate that adds data to the TEventArgs so the receiver can see if the change is from a user interaction or not

Comment: You could also set the true value before adding the event :) Or like @RobertN said save the old state around if you need to, or do some data binding might be easier.

Comment: Switch control is a b*. The triggering of the event is good because it is toggled. It just shouldn't do that on the first databind (in my opinion). The way I worked around it is to do the databinding and attaching the event in C#. First I set IsToggled on the switch, then setBinding on the IsToggledProperty and after that I attach the event.

Maybe this helps some other people here searching for answers.

Comment: Did you find solution on this? I also cant figure it out how to databind on first load especially?

Comment: @batmaci I haven't worked with Xamarin.Forms again, so no, no solution found. I guess I'd unregister the Toggled event before updating it programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're experiencing is correct: every time the `IsToggled` property changes, the switch will fire the `Toggled` event.

I'm not sure if the [Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Switch.Toggled/) has been updated recently, but as of today it says this about the `Toggled` event:

> Event that is raised when this Switch is toggled

## Sample Code

Here is sample code that prevents the `Toggled` event from being handled when the `Toggled` event is not fired by the user

[image]

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SwitchToggle
{
    public class SwitchPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SwitchPage()
        {
            var mySwitch = new Switch
            {
                IsToggled = true
            };
            mySwitch.Toggled += HandleSwitchToggledByUser;

            var toggleButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Toggle The Switch"
            };
            toggleButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                mySwitch.Toggled -= HandleSwitchToggledByUser;
                mySwitch.IsToggled = !mySwitch.IsToggled;
                mySwitch.Toggled += HandleSwitchToggledByUser;
            };

            var mainLayout = new RelativeLayout();

            Func<RelativeLayout, double> getSwitchWidth = (parent) => parent.Measure(mainLayout.Width, mainLayout.Height).Request.Width;
            Func<RelativeLayout, double> getToggleButtonWidth = (parent) => parent.Measure(mainLayout.Width, mainLayout.Height).Request.Width;

            mainLayout.Children.Add(mySwitch,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => parent.Width / 2 - getSwitchWidth(parent) / 2),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => parent.Height / 2 - mySwitch.Height / 2)
            );
            mainLayout.Children.Add(toggleButton,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => parent.Width / 2 - getToggleButtonWidth(parent) / 2),
                Constraint.RelativeToView(mySwitch, (parent, view) => view.Y + view.Height + 10)
            );

            Content = mainLayout;

        }

        async void HandleSwitchToggledByUser(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(
                "Switch Toggled By User",
                "",
                "OK"
            );
        }
    }

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SwitchPage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it's "documentation accurate", but it's still a pain to have to unregister events every time I want to actuate the switch programatically. It doesn't make sense from a functionality point of view.

Comment: Haha, yea, it's a pain. Hopefully this helped answer your question! Let me know if I can add anything more to help!

Comment: Hi Aspyct! If you don't have any follow up questions, let's mark this question as Answered to help anyone in the future when they have a similar question.

Comment: Ah well, fair enough I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Toggled event will every-time called, when you manually change the toggle that time also Toggled event will fire.

The solution is just set

```
mySwitch.Toggled -= HandleSwitchToggledByUser;
```

before you manually change toggle value, and write

```
mySwitch.Toggled += HandleSwitchToggledByUser;
```

after you manual change of toggle,

Hope, this will help you

Comment: Good old Xamarin. As of Xamarin.Forms version 3.6.0.264807 this somehow does not work